# Syntax to automatically export functions in a Julia module

Tags: design-patterns, module, julia

I find it a little tedious to *list out every function* for exporting. And doing this ([pulled from a thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/exportall/4970/13) a couple of years ago) feels bad:

```
module DemoModule
  # 25 functions here...

  for n in names(current_module(), true)
    if Base.isidentifier(n) && n ∉ (Symbol(current_module()), :eval)
      @eval export $n
    end
  end
end
```

Is there syntactic sugar to mark functions to be exported automatically? I'd like to draw an analogy to Python's syntax for public/private methods:

```
module DemoModule

  function add(a, b)
    # `add` is exported automatically
    return _private_helper(a) + _private_helper(b)
  end

  function _private_helper(a)
    # `_private_helper` should not be exported, so it's marked with a `_`
    return a
  end
end
```

---

**Some Additional Context**:

- This pain point is usually in the code/docs interface with `Documenter.jl`. I'm writing in both and realize "*I forgot to export something*".
- There was a lot of discussion around this [for type fields going back to 2015](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12064). [Private properties in types/structs](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/private-properties-in-julia-0-7/10785) have some best practices, and the [style guide was updated ~25 days ago](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/40533) to make this more explicit. I cannot find something analogous for functions though.

---

**Edit**: Came up with a possible compromise: [`ExportPublic.jl`](https://github.com/hayesall/ExportPublic.jl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally considered not recommended throughout discussions in Julia community.

However there is a package `ExportAll.jl` that just exactly that.

```
module Bar
    using ExportAll
    function foo()
        1
    end

    function bar()
        2
    end
    @exportAll()
end
```

Now you can do:

```
julia> using Main.Bar

julia> bar()
2
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the ExportAll package. You're right though: this is exactly what I *don't* want to do. I guess I could tweak the macro to simulate public/private based on method names.

Comment: I hacked on it for a little while and ended up creating `ExportPublic.jl`: https://github.com/hayesall/ExportPublic.jl I'll play around with it some more, it may/may not end up fitting the workflow I like.

Comment: What `SubString(string(e), 8, 8)` does? Which is the rule?

Comment: converts `s` to `String` a creates a `view` on its 8-th character